# Converting a string to a formatted date-time string using Python

Tags: python, datetime, time, strftime, strptime

I'm trying to convert a string "20091229050936" into "05:09 29 December 2009 (UTC)"

```
>>>import time
>>>s = time.strptime("20091229050936", "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
>>>print s.strftime('%H:%M %d %B %Y (UTC)')
```

gives
`AttributeError: 'time.struct_time' object has no attribute 'strftime'`

Clearly, I've made a mistake: time is wrong, it's a datetime object!  It's got a date *and* a time component!

```
>>>import datetime
>>>s = datetime.strptime("20091229050936", "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
```

gives
`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'strptime'`

How am I meant to convert a string into a formatted date-string?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`time.strptime` returns a `time_struct`; `time.strftime` accepts a `time_struct` as an optional parameter:

```
>>>s = time.strptime(page.editTime(), "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
>>>print time.strftime('%H:%M %d %B %Y (UTC)', s)
```

gives
`05:09 29 December 2009 (UTC)`

Answer (score 43):

For `datetime` objects, `strptime` is a [static method](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime) of the `datetime` class, not a free function in the `datetime` module:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> s = datetime.datetime.strptime("20091229050936", "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
>>> print s.strftime('%H:%M %d %B %Y (UTC)')
05:09 29 December 2009 (UTC)
```

Comment: Pedantic point: It's a class method, not a static method. The difference is that class methods are passed the class itself as an argument, and can therefore behave dynamically for subclasses; alternate constructors (like `strptime`) are always (or at least should always) be class methods.

Answer (score 2):

For me this is the best and it works on Google App Engine as well

Example showing UTC-4

```
import datetime   
UTC_OFFSET = 4
local_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()
print (local_datetime - datetime.timedelta(hours=UTC_OFFSET)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from datetime import datetime
s = datetime.strptime("20091229050936", "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
print("{:%H:%M %d %B %Y (UTC)}".format(s))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [easy_date](https://github.com/ralphavalon/easy_date) to make it easy:

```
import date_converter
my_datetime = date_converter.string_to_string("20091229050936", "%Y%m%d%H%M%S", "%H:%M %d %B %Y (UTC)")
```