# python - convert date input to date output without time

Tags: python, datetime

Input is: 2011-01-01
Output is: 2011-01-01 00:00:00

How do it get it to output to be: 2011-01-01 ??

```
# Packages
import datetime

def ObtainDate():
    global d
    isValid=False
    while not isValid:
        userInDate = raw_input("Type Date yyyy-mm-dd: ")
        try: # strptime throws an exception if the input doesn't match the pattern
            d = datetime.datetime.strptime(userInDate, '%Y-%m-%d')
            isValid=True
        except:
            print "Invalid Input. Please try again.\n"
    return d


print ObtainDate()
```

actually not the same as the reference.  I'm asking just for the date not the time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting a string to a formatted date-time string using Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316987/converting-a-string-to-a-formatted-date-time-string-using-python)

Comment: You can format the output just like you formatted the input. Change a single letter (`strptime` to `strftime`) and you're 99% of the way there.

Comment: doing that gives me an invalid input.

Comment: Actually, you can just try the parse and, if successful, assign `d = userInDate`, since you just wanted to check whether the input was valid (added to answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just format the parsed object with your desired formatting.

```
d = datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.strptime(userInDate, '%Y-%m-%d'), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

```
>>> d
'2015-05-09'
```

...Actually, if you don't want to change the formatting at all, just do this:

```
try: # strptime throws an exception if the input doesn't match the pattern
    datetime.datetime.strptime(userInDate, '%Y-%m-%d')
except ValueError:
    print "Invalid Input. Please try again.\n"
else:
    isValid=True
    d = userInDate
```

In fact, you can skip `datetime` entirely if you want speed:

```
if userInDate.replace('-','').isdigit() and len(userInDate) == 10 and userInDate[4] == userInDate[7] == '-':
    d = userInDate
```