# How to convert a given date in format YYYYMMDD to previous day

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, datetime

The dates are in format "YYYYMMDD" and I want it in "YYYYMMDD-(1)", i.e previous day.

For example consider date 20080101 the previous date would be 20071231.

Is there any built in function to do this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to subtract a day from a date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441147/how-to-subtract-a-day-from-a-date)

Comment: convert string to date, substract a day, convert date to string in your format. Even better: store dates as datetime.date to begin with and do not care about the format unless you print it. Solutions for these part-problems are galore on SO - search them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a string to a formatted date-time string using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316987/converting-a-string-to-a-formatted-date-time-string-using-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can perform this transformation in 3 steps:

1. Convert string to `datetime`.
2. Subtract one day.
3. Convert `datetime` object to `str`.

Here is an example:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

x = '20080101'
f = '%Y%m%d'

res = (datetime.strptime(x, f) - timedelta(days=1)).strftime(f)
# '20071231'
```