# Convert datetime into standard time python

Tags: python, datetime, time

I am trying to convert time data which is displayed in hours minutes and seconds into standard time. I want to discard the seconds as well.
I'm selecting datetime from mysql like this

```
time = connect("SELECT","""SELECT datTime FROM myTable WHERE ID = 1;""")
```

I then get only the time by doing this

```
time = time[0][0].time()
```

And I have tried various methods of converting the time into standard time minus the seconds such as

```
noSeconds = time.strftime("%H:%M")


timeNoSec = datetime.strptime(noSeconds, '%H:%M')

standardTime = noSeconds.strftime('%I:%M %p')

print(standardTime)
```

but I just get the following error

```
standardTime = noSeconds.strftime('%I:%M %p')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'
```

Comment: What do you mean by "standard time"?  Do you mean the Unix `time_t` value, seconds since 1/1/1970, as returned by `time.time()`?  The `datetime` module calls this a timestamp.  Look for the `totimestamp` methods.  Perhaps you should show an example of exactly what string you want.

Comment: Did you mean `timeNoSec.strftime('%I:%M %p')`? Or directly `time[0][0].strftime('%I:%M %p')`?

Comment: By standard time I mean something like 8:30 pm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the variable time is a string and not a time format, so none of the ways you tried work.
To convert I found this:

```py
import datetime

origin = '2022-01-11 15:51:00'

time_total = datetime.datetime.strptime(origin, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
timeNoSec =  time_total.strftime("%H:%M")
print (timeNoSec)

15:51
```

[From this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316987/converting-a-string-to-a-formatted-date-time-string-using-python)

Comment: when i try this i get the following error `ValueError: time data '2022-01-11 15:51:00' does not match format '%Y%m%d%H%M%S'`

Comment: sorry, my mistake, you have to put the separation between the formatting, like this: 
`strptime(time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")`
I will edit the post for better understanding